# mips programming. *stuck at while loop

Tags: while-loop, mips

*help. i"m stuck in the loop..how do i correct it?

Read a string and store it in memory. Limit the string length to 100 characters. Then, convert each letter to a number. Letter ‘A’ or ‘a’ is equal to 1. Letter ‘B’ or ‘b’ is equal to 2. Finally, letter ‘Z’ or ‘z’ is equal to 26. All other characters, digits, or space s should be discarded (not counted). Compute the string value as the sum of all letter values, and display the string value as an integer. At the end, ask the user whether he wants to repeat the program. 
 
Here is a sample run:

```
Enter a string of at most 100 characters: 
MIPS programming is fun. 
String value = 257 
Repeat (Y/N)? n
```

And the code:

```
.data
again: .asciiz "Repeat (Y/N)? "     
Prompt: .ascii "Enter a string of at most 100 characters: "       
answer: .space 256

.text  
.globl main  

main:
    #addi $t0, $zero, 0 #initial i=0


while:
    beq $t0, 'n', exit
        beq $t0, 'N', exit


        jal printWord
    #addi $t0, $t0,1

        li  $v0, 4  
        la  $a0, again  
    syscall  

        la  $a0, answer
        li  $a1, 3
        li  $v0, 8
    syscall

        lb  $t0, 0($a0)

    j while

exit:

    li $v0, 10
    syscall


#function call

printWord:
    la $a0, Prompt
    li $v0, 4   #4 print string from prompt
    syscall


    li $a1, 101 #only 100 characters can be input
    li $v0, 8   #8 read string from prompt
    syscall


    li $v0, 4   #1 print string entered
    syscall

    jr $ra
```

Comment: You haven't clearly explained what your problem is. If you want to get help with your problem, you may need to review this guide on how to ask better questions http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have you verified that `$t0` contains the value you expect it to after reading user's input?

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't appear to match the sample output (I don't see `String value = 257` being printed from anywhere). Also, in `printWord` you don't properly set up `$a0` before using syscall 8.